# Export xls and send it via email

Tags: google-apps-script

This code worked fine until 20.02.2014.
Now it report error 302 «Moved Temporarily». This problem seems to be in added authentication and redirect, but I didn't found the right answer. Please, help me find a solution or workaround for this problem.

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always"};
}

function sendDailyNewsEmailReport(){
  var emails = "my@mail.net";
  var sourceDocument = SpreadsheetApp.create("DailyReport");
  var sourceDocumentId = sourceDocument.getId();
  sourceDocument.getUrl();
  var id = sourceDocumentId;
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls', googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob();
  var myMail = "Automated Report " + reportDate + ".";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emails, "DailyReport (" + reportDate + ")" , "", {htmlBody: myMail, attachments: doc.setName("DailyNewsReport(" + reportDate + ").xls")});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this as the last line for googleOAuth_ function

```
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always",muteHttpExceptions:true};
```

Comment: No way. I tried this before. Got excel file with "Moved Temporary. The document has moved here."

Comment: You need to run the code once within script editor. This will prompt it you to authorize. I faced this problem yesterday, and once I authorized the app (and after I added muteHttpExceptions) it worked.

Comment: Not working... I'am running it from script editor, no authorize request promted. I'am even made new script file for test.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code in new scripted document:

```
function googleOAuth_(name,scope) {
  var oAuthConfig = UrlFetchApp.addOAuthService(name);
  oAuthConfig.setRequestTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?scope="+scope);
  oAuthConfig.setAuthorizationUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken");
  oAuthConfig.setAccessTokenUrl("https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetAccessToken");
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerKey('anonymous');
  oAuthConfig.setConsumerSecret('anonymous');
  return {oAuthServiceName:name, oAuthUseToken:"always", muteHttpExceptions:true};
}

function sendDailyNewsEmailReport(){
  var emails = "enter@your.mail";
  var sourceDocument = SpreadsheetApp.create("DailyReport");
  var sourceDocumentId = sourceDocument.getId();
  sourceDocument.getUrl();
  var id = sourceDocumentId;
  var url = 'https://docs.google.com/feeds/';
  var doc = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+'download/spreadsheets/Export?key='+id+'&exportFormat=xls', googleOAuth_('docs',url)).getBlob();
  var myMail = "Automated Report TEST";
  MailApp.sendEmail(emails, "DailyReport" , "", {htmlBody: myMail, attachments: doc.setName("DailyNewsReport.xls")});
}
```

Was asked twice for authorize and then I got file with «Moved Temporarily» again...